# Would you help me with prefixes?

Tags: prefixes

Ultrasonic

Supersonic

Would anybody explain me whether is there any difference between the followings or Not?

Ultra-

Super-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both "ultra-" and "super-" have a connotation of "above the norm," however, there are a couple key differences.

"Ultra-" tends to mean "to the furthest possible extreme," whereas "super-" tends to imply something which is simply higher or, literally, above. Here are a few examples:

- **Superimpose**: Superimpose means (typically in photography) to place one image on top of another so you can see both. This word is preceded by "super" as, while one image is above another, it is not an extreme. "Ultraimpose" doesn't make sense, since there is no way to maximally place two images on top of each other.
- **Ultraviolet**: Ultraviolet refers to the colors just above violet. These colors are the highest possible violet colors - so high that we can't actually see them. "Superviolet" doesn't make sense here, since "super" would simply imply something which is very, very violet-colored.

Comment: Thank you so much.  The explanations of your site are THE GREATEST. Thank you a lot.